# Is possible to reuse DOMString returned from HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() or canvas.toBlob()?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, canvas, frontend

I am setting up an image Cropper, it will give me width and height,X and Y of cropped details. Using that I am creating a preview image (using canvas) but is it possible to store that data returned from `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()` or `canvas.toBlob()` and reuse in other devices and browsers?

Refer below link (it uses `canvas.toBlob()` method)
https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this lines of code:

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
  value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
     arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
  }
 });
}
```

Just change to your code.
Please LMK soon.

Comment: seems like its a polyfill if HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob() is not present in browser.?

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can convert Blob to base64 string,
and save it on server side.

So you can serve this media later to different user/browser.

The way to do it is:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // converts the blob to base64 and calls onload

reader.onload = function() {
  data = reader.result; // data url as base 64 encoded string.
};
```

Decoding this string will get you the binary PNG data.

Comment: In the front-end,can I store data in the json file and that json will be sent to all the users who will read from data and use the image.is it correct way of doing ? and will  it work?